# Property 'videoThumb' does not exist on type 'UnionType'. Property 'videoThumb' does not exist on type 'Image'

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Estou criando um componente com react e typescript e estou tendo este erro:

> Property 'videoThumb' does not exist on type 'UnionType'.
> Property 'videoThumb' does not exist on type 'Image'.

basicamente o problema esta ocorrendo na linha 52 onde dentro do if eu verifico se "thumb" tem a propriedade "videoThumb". O tipo de dado que eu recebo pode ser ou igual uma interface Video ou uma Image.

Este erro também acontece com o thumb.imageUrl

> Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type 'UnionType'.
> Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type 'Video'.

bom aqui está o componente:

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import { useProduct } from 'vtex.product-context'
import './index.global.css';

const sliderSetting = {
    centerMode: false,
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 767,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 1050,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
            }
        }
    ]
};

interface Image {
    imageUrl: string
    imageId: string
    imageLabel: string
    imageTag: string
    imageText: string
}

interface Video {
    videoThumb: string
}

type UnionType = Video | Image

const Galeria: React.FC = () => {
    const { product } = useProduct() || {}

    const images: Array<UnionType> = product?.items[0].images!

    function renderThumbnails(): JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element {
        if (!images) return <></>;
        return images.map((thumb, index): JSX.Element =>  {
            if(thumb.videoThumb) {
                return <li key={index}><img src={thumb.videoThumb} height="36px" width="36px"/></li>
            }else {
                return  <li key={index}><img src={thumb.imageUrl} height="36px" width="36px"/></li>
            }
        })
    } 

  return (
      <div className="gallery">
          <Slider {...sliderSetting}>
            {renderThumbnails()}
          </Slider>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Galeria;
```

Answer (score -1):

Voce definiu que o seu array de imagens do tipo UnionType pode ser ou vídeo ou imagem, e não os dois ao mesmo tempo, por isso dá esse erro.

mude:

```
type UnionType = Video | Image
```

Para:

```
type UnionType = Video & Image
```

Comment: Testei isso, porém ele dá um erro novo na linha onde eu declaro o images `Type '{ imageId: string; imageLabel: string; imageTag: string; imageUrl: string; imageText: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'UnionType[]'.
  Type '{ imageId: string; imageLabel: string; imageTag: string; imageUrl: string; imageText: string; }' is not assignable to type 'UnionType'.
    Property 'videoThumb' is missing in type '{ imageId: string; imageLabel: string; imageTag: string; imageUrl: string; imageText: string; }' but required in type 'Video'.ts(2322)
index.tsx(34, 5): 'videoThumb' is declared here.`